# Looking for a timeout function in Python that will run on Windows

Tags: python, selenium

I've got a Python program on Windows 10 that runs a loop thousands of times with multiple functions that can sometimes hang and stop the program execution.  Some are IO functions, and some are selenium webdriver functions.  I'm trying to build a mechanism that will let me run a function, then kill that function after a specified number of seconds and try it again if that function didn't finish.  If the function completes normally, let the program execution continue without waiting for the timeout to finish.

I've looked at at least a dozen different solutions, and can't find something that fits my requirements.  Many require SIGNALS which is not available on Windows.  Some spawn processes or threads which consume resources that can't easily be released, which is a problem when I'm going to run these functions thousands of times.  Some work for very simple functions, but fail when a function makes a call to another function.

The situations this must work for:

1. Must run on Windows 10
2. A "driver.get" command for selenium webdriver to read a web page
3. A function that reads from or writes to a text file
4. A function that runs an external command (like checking my IP address or connecting to a VPN server)

I need to be able to specify a different timeout for each of these situations.  A file write should take < 2 seconds, whereas a VPN server connection may take 20 seconds.

I've tried the following function libraries:

1. [timeout-decorator 0.5.0](https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/)
2. [wrapt-timeout-decorator 1.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt-timeout-decorator/)
3. [func-timeout 4.3.5](https://pypi.org/project/func-timeout/)

Here is a trimmed version of my program that includes the functions I need to wrap in a timeout function:

```
import csv
import time
from datetime import date 
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request

cities = []
total_cities = 0
city = ''
city_counter = 0
results = []

temp = ''
temp2 = 'IP address not found'
driver = None
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Read city list
    with open('citylist.csv') as csvfile:
        readCity = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n');
        for row in csvfile:
            city = row.replace('\n','')
            cities.append(city.replace('"',''))
    
    #Get my IP address
    try:
        temp = urllib.request.urlopen('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
        temp = str(temp.read())
        found = temp.find(':')
        found2 = temp.find('<',found)
    except:
        pass
        
    if (temp.find('IP Address:') > -1):
        temp2 = temp[found+2:found2]

    print(' IP: [',temp2,']\n',sep='')
    
    total_cities = len(cities)
    
    ## Open browser for automation
    try: driver.close()
    except AttributeError: driver = None
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    #Search for links
    while (city_counter < total_cities):
        city = cities[city_counter]     
        
        searchTerm = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=skate park ' + city

        ## Perform search using designated search term
        driver.get(searchTerm)
        haystack = driver.page_source
                
        driver.get(searchTerm)
            
        found = 0
        found2 = 0
        while (found > -1):
            found = haystack.find('<a href=',found2)
            found2 = haystack.find('"',found+10)
            if (haystack[found+9:found+13] == 'http'):
                results.append(haystack[found+9:found2])
        
        city_counter += 1
    
    driver.close()
    
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(results):
        print(counter,': ',results[counter],sep='')
        counter += 1
```

The citylist.csv file:

```
"Oakland, CA",
"San Francisco, CA",
"San Jose, CA"
```

Comment: When you speak of "spawn[ing] processes or threads which consume resources that can't easily be released", are you talking about the overhead of creating & managing threads? The usual solution to that problem is to use thread pools. Platforms like .NET tend to do that under the hood with time-consuming I/O functions like yours, and func-timeout looks amenable to that approach in Python.